# Webscraping with selenium in Python - if xtag value is empty return NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have a script which loops through a few URLs which have the same layout. I need to capture the data for a certain field which has the same xpath for all the URLs. This info is stored in a list, here's my code:

```
field_list = [ ]
fields =driver.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
for f in fields:
     field_list.append(f.text)
```

However on some pages the field is empty.

If I `print len(field_list)` output is 13
But if I do

```
for f in field_list:
    print(f)
```

Output is 11 lines

Basically the non filled in fields are appended to the list at the end. Is there a way to convert them to none type or NaN?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Why can't you add to list only if text is not none.

Answer (score 0):

I would check for the existence of text in the element, *before* appending it to the list, ex:

```
field_list = []
fields = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
for f in fields:
    fText = f.text
    if not fText.strip(): field_list.append(None)
    else: field_list.append(fText)
```

if you would rather evaluate the list *after* you store the values, you can do something like this:

```
field_list = []
fields = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('xpath')
for f in fields:
    field_list.append(f.text)

new_list = [x if x.strip() else None for x in field_list]

for f in new_list:
    print(f)
```

the **output** of the print at the end should still be 13 objects, but the empty ones make it *appear* like 11, assuming there are 2 empty strings. Converting the empty strings to `None` type should be better for printing and viewing the data later, if you'd like to know if there were ***empty*** text objects scraped.